# BigBlueButton H.264 & AAC Royalties/fees Required?

Tags: licensing, mp4, h.264, bigbluebutton

Looking to implement a small BigBlueButton server but leadership is asking about whether any royalties/fees need to be taken into consideration.

In particular, BigBlueButton recordings are in MP4 format so they are wondering whether any H.264 & AAC encoding royalties are required?  Any point in right direction is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to only pay royalty fees if you are charging for content, if you are not charging for content then H.264 is free to use [see this release](http://www.mpegla.com/Lists/MPEG%20LA%20News%20List/Attachments/74/n-10-08-26.pdf).

Also bigbluebutton does not use H.264 encoder/decoder even for playback as it respects the commercial license agreements and supports only WebM for this( from version 0.81 the latest), so you don't need to worry about the same (See [this](https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/issues/detail?id=640) discussion about H.264)